# Meaning of chitraguptha and its corresponding entity in Jiva

Tags: terminology, yama, interpretation, nirukta

Chitragupta, according to widely known belief, is a god who stays near Yama and records all the karma of an individual.

The actual meaning of Yama, [according to a dictionary](https://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php?w=%E0%B0%AF%E0%B0%AE) is

> The one who decides the results based on the karma of a jiva

Similarly, the [meaning of word chitraguptha](https://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php?w=%E0%B0%9A%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%A4%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%97%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%AA%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%A4) is

> The one who stores the list of karma of a jiva

Yama is a form of parabrahman who deals with the proper treatment to Jivas based on their karma.

Coming to chirtagupta, is it same as **antahkarana**?  The name of the term may be different. I am thinking that antahkarana is the name of the entity of a jiva that stores the impressions of karma of a jiva and based on which the jiva attains results in different lokas.

Is this interpretation true? Can chitraguptha, who stores all the list of karmic activities of a jiva, be interpreted as antahkarana?

---

If anyone is unaware of the Yama or Chitragupta, can read the following statements

> Thereupon, the people will go near Yama as before after being tied
> with ropes by the attendants. Taking the writing (of Chitragupta) as
> authority, there will be persons occupying hell. Thus what you do will
> be splendid.
>
> [[72, Chapter 7: The statement of Brahma, Uttara Bhaga, Narada Purana]](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n239/mode/2up?)

Comment: Please give a reference for your story. The Lord (Iswara) is the giver of the fruits of karma; the Lord is not a bookkeeper. Brahma Sutras 3.2.38-39, Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.24

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda For what statements, do you want a reference?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Yes, the gist of the interpretation is the same. Parabrahman may not maintain a book of all karma. Anthakarana stores it automatically, so I am comparing and equating them.